# Cd4030 vs CD4070 exclusive Or gate

Tags: cmos

is there is difference between the CD4030 and CD4070?

both are Quad Exclusive-OR Gates, the only difference i can tell that the Texas instruments datasheet from the Cd4070 is newer.
both are rated for 20 Volt.

> Medium Speed Operation
>
> - t PHL, tPLH = 65ns (Typ) at VDD = 10V, CL = 50pF

even that looks the same ... and the pin out.

why did they border to make 2 ic's?

Comment: Due to the ‘Zoolander’ effect.

Comment: @Kartman lol, a couple of days ago, i picked the Cd4030, now i'm scrolling through the list to see if i can find something useful and find another XOR gate, the same counts for the Cd4016 and CD4066 and probably some more. why not just call it a revision, b, c or d version.

Comment: You don't know that they made two different chips...they may have just made two different datasheets, so they could be a second-source for old Harris part numbers.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson so i should take the Cd4070 instead of the CD4030?

Comment: You should use whichever part meets your requirements and is available to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an issue with the original cd4030 (back in the mid- to late-70s?) - input capacitance was high so it would glitch with short pulses so a "corrected" cd4070 was launched by RCA and Motorola.  When the 40XXB series was launched, they used the same chip for cd4030B and cd4070B.

The list of logic chips was already well established so it would cause confusion if the 4030 was missing and many lists didn't contain a 4070 - designers would be confused if they couldn't get a 4030 from the distributor.  I had one of the old RCA posters of 4000 series parts in my basement for years until I had some water damage. I doubt it listed the 4070.

Comment: so basically the CD4030 currently in the part stores are the same silicon ( when from the same manufacturer) in 2021?

Comment: Yes.  I don't know why the prices are different. Maybe just an issue of what the public is asking for vs availability from the manufacturer with each the specific part number you may want. Or a aerospace repair must use.

Comment: my "dealer" is basically asking the same price for both. 0.720€ (CD4030) and 0.750€ (CD4070). but could be a (Philips) HEF part.

Comment: Seems to be "the same" when you need a handful but corporate purchasing teams get pretty interested when they're buying millions and they see a 4% difference.